# How to hide the expand/collapse icon for the detail grid in kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo ui grid detail Template. In the grid i have a dropdown with some values like   dropdown, textbox etc. If i add the new record then i don't want to show the expand/collapse icon. After selecting the dropdown and the selected value will be dropdown then only i want to show the expand/collapse icon. How can i able to do this using kendo ui. Hope you understand my quesion.
     I have tried to access that in the dataBound Event like this

```
     dataBound: function (e) {         

                var dataSource = this.dataSource;         
                this.element.find('tr.k-master-row').each(function() {

                    this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row>.k-hierarchy-cell>a").hide();

                });
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
function dataBound() {
    var grid = this;

    //expand all detail rows
    grid.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").each(function () {
        grid.expandRow($(this));
    })

    //remove hierarchy cells and column
    $(".k-hierarchy-cell").remove();
    $(".k-hierarchy-col").remove();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way we can keep that arrow component, move it to the detail template itself and hide the column?

Comment: @Neophile Not sure, I have not the environment to try it now, sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to set the `Width()` to look like it's hidden.

```
function dataBound() {
    $(".k-hierarchy-cell", "#gridName").width(0.1);
    $(".k-hierarchy-col", "#gridName").width(0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Kendo's MVC helper, it' way easier to do this that way:

```
$(".k-hierarchy-cell").hide();
$(".k-hierarchy-col").remove();
```

It hides first default column (with icon) but in the same time it keeps other columns in right position.

Answer (score 1):

if you wonder how to do it with React without using jQuery, I ended up using cellRender props.

````
....
const cellRender = (tdElement, cellProps) => {
    if (cellProps.field === 'expanded') { // this is the expand column you want to hide
        if (cellProps.dataItem.ProductName !== 'Chai') { // Condition goes here. I disabled all expand icon if ProductName is not Chai
            return <td> </td>;
        }
    }
    return tdElement;
};

return (
    <Grid
      ...
        cellRender={cellRender}
      ...
    >
        <Column field="ProductName" title="Product" width="300px" />
        <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="50px" />
        <Column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" width="100px" />
        <Column field="QuantityPerUnit" title="Qty Per Unit" />
    </Grid>
);```
````

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
                some content
            </script>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: [
                          {FirstName: "name1", hasChildren: true},
                          {FirstName: "name2", hasChildren: false}
                        ],
                        height: 550,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: false,
                        detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
                        detailInit: detailInit,
                        dataBound: function(e) {
                            var items = e.sender.items();
                            items.each(function(){
                              var row = $(this);
                              var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);
                              if(!dataItem.hasChildren){
                                row.find(".k-hierarchy-cell").html(""); //It will hide 
                              }

                            })
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "FirstName",
                                title: "First Name",
                                width: "120px"
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });

                function detailInit(e) {

                }
            </script>

        </div>
```

Comment: While any answer is appreciated, code only answers are likely to not be understand well especially by people with similar problems. Please consider adding some detail to your answer (how your solution works...)

Answer (score -1):

To conditionally show the grid row details arrow, add a databound event to your grid that has the detail template.  In the databound event, call this function:

```
                dataBound: function (e) {                            // on data bound
                    var items = e.sender.items();                    // find all rows
                    items.each(function() {                          // for each row
                        var row = $(this);                           // 
                        var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);       // get the data item of the row
                        if (!dataItem.HasChildren) {                 // check for children
                            row.find(".k-hierarchy-cell").html("");  // if no children, hide arrow
                        }
                    });
                }
```